# cant access details other than "name" from FB.api in ajax function

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

i have a problem with accessing user details like first_name, last_name, id and email, but i can access name directly. i can access user name by this code:

```
function testAPI()
{      
  console.log('Welcome!  Fetching your information.... ');

  FB.api(
    '/me',
    'GET',
    {"fields":"id,name,first_name,last_name,email"},
    function(response)
    {
      f_id = response.id;
      name = response.name;
      fname = response.first_name;
      lname = response.last_name;
      email = response.email;

      console.log('Successful login for: ' + name + "\n first name: " + fname + "\n last name: " + lname + "\n email: " + email  + "\n ID: " + f_id);
      document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = 'Thanks for logging in, ' + response.name + '!';
    }
  );
  $.ajax(
    {
      type:"POST",
      url: 'http://localhost:8080/timeline_dashboard/index.php',

      // data: {f_id: f_id, name: name, fname: fname, lname: lname, email: email},
      data: {name:name},
      success: function(data)
      {
      alert(data);
      }
    }
  );
}

$(document).ready(
  function()
  {
    var f_id, name, fname, lname, email;
  }
);

<?php //working code on index.php
// print_r($_POST);die;
  if(isset($_POST['name']))
  {
    echo $_POST['name'];die;
  }
?>
```

in this above code i sent the value of 'name' through ajax call and able to get that value through 'POST' method to index.php and when i change `data: {name:name},` to `data: {email:email},` or anything like id, first_name or last_name i always get this error : `ReferenceError: email is not defined` in console, which means my ajax function is not getting any variable named email inside scope of testAPI(). So finally my question is how to get variables other than name, so that i can sent these var as argument in data of ajax call AND access on index.php page so i can use these variables i got from $_POST to insert into database for user registration on my webapp? got this from tutorials on [facebook's tutorial](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/web/#example)

Comment: Have you logged `response` to console and inspected it?

Comment: You should rather not be doing this on the client side to begin with. I could send any arbitrary data to your server-side endpoint, that has nothing whatsoever to do with my actual user data as known to Facebook. You should send only the access token to the server, and then make the API calls to request this data from there.

Comment: i cant get value of response object out of FB.api function, if i could then i would've directly use used it to retrieve value of user details

Comment: What are you even talking about? Put `console.log(response)` as the first line into your callback function …

Comment: yup did it and it shows the object from JSON response file but what about that ?

Comment: You are not handling the asynchronous nature of the API correctly here. Your AJAX request belongs _inside_ the callback function, not “after” it. (“After” in quotes, because that only means after in code order here, not regarding the order in which things actually execute.)